# Get date less 1 day

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sum, where-clause

I want to know the data for September 19th.

When the 20-day value is entered, I don't know how to express the expression of the variable to get the value of the day before.
(@TransDate-1) <---- 
How can I fix this?   (datatype is only varchar)

```
DECLARE @TransDate VARCHAR(10)
SET @TransDate = '2019-09-20'

SELECT ItemCode, SUM(Quantity)
FROM INVENTORYOUTDETAIL
WHERE TransDate <= @TransDate-1 AND FacilityCode = '10' AND OutType='MOVE' 
GROUP BY ItemCode
```

Comment: [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @TransDate probably should be date or datetime, not varchar(10).  You may need to convert(date,@TransDate) if you can't change it.

Comment: Is the column `TransDate` also a `varchar` and does it only ever store a date, never a time component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DATEADD()`:

```
DATEADD(day, -1, @TransDate)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=749caa1cbd492f5fbdda464d2674679e)**:

```
DECLARE @TransDate DATE
SET @TransDate = '2019-09-20'
SELECT DATEADD(day, -1, @TransDate)
```

```
| (No column name)    |
| :------------------ |
| 19/09/2019 00:00:00 |
```

In your query:

```
SELECT ItemCode, SUM(Quantity)
FROM INVENTORYOUTDETAIL
WHERE 
    TransDate <= DATEADD(day, -1, @TransDate) 
    AND FacilityCode = '10' 
    AND OutType='MOVE' 
GROUP BY ItemCode
```

---

Note: you should be declaring variable `@TransDate`  as a `DATE` rather than `VARCHAR`, and then:

- if column `TransDate` has a `DATE`-like datatye, you can compare it directly with the variable
- if column `TransDate` is a `VARCHAR`, the safest way to proceed is to convert it to a `DATE` first before comparison, so: `CONVERT(date, TransDate) <= DATEADD(day, -1, @TransDate)`

Comment: If the column `TransDate` is also a `varchar` will SQL Server do an implicit conversion to a datetime and therefore a datetime compare? Or will it do an implicit conversion of the variable `@TransDate` to `varchar` and to a string compare?

Comment: @DaleBurrell: good point...  This seems to work in  [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3fba4c635d8308a9537f42afaa42cd43), but not sure that this simple test is enough to confirm that.

Comment: @DaleBurrell: I edited my answer with a few thoughts on datatypes of the variable and column.

Comment: Note for OP: This illustrates why it is important to use the correct datatypes when designing your database. Having to convert the `TransDate` column to a `date` datatype will cause a performance hit due to being unable to use any index on that column.